# a continuous extension from a space to itself

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be $T_{2}$ and for every closed subset $K$ of $X$ and a continuous
map $f:K \rightarrow X$ there is a continuous extension of $f$.

Does the Cantor $2^{\mathbb N}$ (Hilbert Cube) space have this property? If yes please why?
Any other interesting spaces have this property?

Answer (score 1):

For the Cantor space $2^\omega$ it is true, since for every closed subset $K$ of $2^\omega$ there is a retraction $r:2^\omega\to K$, ie. such continuous function that $r|_K=id_K$ (look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/250483/c-be-a-closed-subset-of-the-cantor-set-delta-show-the-existence-of-a-conti)). Now for a mapping $f:K\to 2^\omega$ the composition $f\circ r:2^\omega\to 2^\omega$ is an extension of $f$ to all $2^\omega$.